# Parametrized route returns undefined variable laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm making a test application. I want to make a table showing all the questions so far, but for each question to have Edit and Remove buttons that would lead the controller functions to edit/delete them. However, for some reason, when I define the onclick event of the edit button and call the route edit with parameter $id, the thing says that $id is undefined, even though the questions are sent to the view.

**Blade**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="row">
            <button type = "submit" onclick="window.location='{{ URL::route('questions.create'); }}'">Add new Question</button>
            @if (sizeof($questions) == 0)
            <h1>No Questions yet...</h1>
            @else
            @foreach ($questions as $q)
            <table id = "questionsTable">
                <thead>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Question</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Is in learning session</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Remove</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr><td>{{ $q->id }}</td><td>{{ $q->text }}</td><td>{{ $q->type }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $q->isInSession }}</td>
                    <td><button type = "submit" onclick = "window.location='{{ URL::route('questions.edit', $q->id); }}'">Edit</button></td></tr>                        <td><button type = "submit" onclick = "{{route('questions.remove', $q->id);}}">Remove</button></td></tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
            @endforeach
            @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

The code for the edit controller function is the following so far:

```
    public function edit(Question $id){
        dd($id);
    }
```

Please tell me how to fix this!

Comment: it would be `$question` as `edit(Question $question)`

Comment: @sta yes, i just found a video about route model binding and saw that i should pass an object, and not an id of some object, and managed to solve it. Thanks for the time you wasted to help me out!